# In Emacs, is there a way to auto-complete only from one specified buffer?

Tags: emacs, autocomplete

When using <kbd>M-/</kbd>, the text in the current buffer is autocompleted with suggestions out of all active buffers.

Is there a way to limit the suggestions to only one specific buffer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about `dabbrev-expand` (<kbd>M-/</kbd> is the usual binding), then there are a variety of options depending on your requirements.

To search only a specific white list of buffers, the simplest approach is to set the variable `dabbrev-search-these-buffers-only`:

```
  "If non-nil, a list of buffers which dabbrev should search.
If this variable is non-nil, dabbrev will only look in these buffers.
It will not even look in the current buffer if it is not a member of
this list."
```

Here's an example from a custom mode of mine (I rebind `M-/` to this function for this mode)

```el
(defun tks-dabbrev-expand (arg)
  "Expand either aliases or descriptions, depending on context."
  (interactive "*P")
  (let* ((candidates
          (if (looking-back "^\\S-+")
              " *tks-aliases*"
            " *tks-descriptions*"))
         (dabbrev-search-these-buffers-only (list (get-buffer candidates))))
    (dabbrev-expand arg)))
```

Note that there are several other ways in which you can filter the list of buffers which dabbrev will search inside. The dabbrev customize group has the details:
<kbd>M-x</kbd> `customize-group` <kbd>RET</kbd> `dabbrev` <kbd>RET</kbd>